# Glusterfs in a container or in the host machine?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, glusterfs

I have a virtual machine running an application which uses 4 Docker containers (also inside the virtual machine).
I need these containers to share their files in a shared filesystem so I thought about Glusterfs.

Now my question is: Where should I install this Glusterfs host? In another container? or in the virtual machine itself?

What are the pros and the cons of both alternatives? I see in many tutorials that they use Glusterfs in a container but what if this container fails or disconnect from the network?